# How do I fix the position of the buttons at centre irrespective of window size in html

Tags: html, css

I would like to maintain the position of the buttons at the center and without overlapping each other in HTML. With my code the button overlap, if I reduce the window size, is there a way to prevent this.
Before resizing the window.

[image]
After resizing the window.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank You.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .clear_btn{
            position:absolute;
            margin-left:40%;
            width:150px;
            bottom:280px
            float: left;
            text-align:center;
            align:center;
            font-size: 18px;
            background-color : white;
        }
        .exit_btn{
            position:absolute;
            margin-left:50%;
            width:150px;
            bottom:280px
            float: left;
            background-color:white;
            font-size: 18px;
            text-align:center;
        }

        .header{
            text-align: center;
            background-color:#101820;
            font-size: 28px;
            color:white;
            height: 70px;
            line-height: 70px;
            font-family:"Open Sans", sans;
        }
        .container{
            background-color:#101820;
            height:50px;
            width:auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="header">
        <h2>
            CONSOLE
        </h2>

    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8050/log_stream">
    <button class="clear_btn">
                CLEAR
    </button>
    </a>
    <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8050/">
    <button class="exit_btn">
                EXIT
    </button>
    </a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach would be

```css
.btn {
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px 16px;
    width: 150px;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #101820;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: white;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans;
}

.container {
    background-color: #101820;
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
        <h2>
            CONSOLE
        </h2>

    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8050/log_stream">
            <button class="btn">
                CLEAR
            </button>
        </a>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8050/">
            <button class="btn">
                EXIT
            </button>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Whats the differenct between this and mine implementation?

Comment: you've written button css twice which does not comply with the DRY principle i.e: DO NOT REPEAT YOURSELF
whereas i just wrote it once and applied twice complying with the DRY principle

Comment: I kept them purposefully to make the user aware which all properties is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Rather that using `position: absolute` and `margin-left` for setting the position, use `flex` properties.

```css
.clear_btn {
  /* position: absolute;
  margin-left: 40%; */
  width: 150px;
  /* bottom: 280px; */
  /* float: left; */
  text-align: center;
  /* align: center; */
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: white;
}

.exit_btn {
  /* position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50%; */
  width: 150px;
  /* bottom: 280px; */
  /* float: left; */
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #101820;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: white;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans;
}

.container {
  background-color: #101820;
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>CONSOLE</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8050/log_stream">
    <button class="clear_btn">CLEAR</button>
  </a>
  <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8050/">
    <button class="exit_btn">EXIT</button>
  </a>
</div>
```